# How to split the success output from an Ajax post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax post to a PHP file which returns a table on success. I use the whole success output to fill a div in my main HTML page. It is pretty simple. However, sometimes the result table is huge and it takes too long to display the results at once or it fails(Google Chrome 'aw snap error').

So, I would like to split the output and load it as user scrolls down.

Let's say,

Ajax success got 1000 results and I want to fill first 20 and display the rest as user scrolls down.

```
        $.ajax({
            url:"xxxxxx.php", 
            data: { xxxxxxxxx },
            type: "POST", 
            success:function(result){
                document.getElementById("cdr").innerHTML =  result;
        });
```

Comment: what format is `result`?

Comment: the format of the result is html table.

Comment: so, it starts with `<table>` tag?

Comment: yes, exactly. starts with  <table>

Comment: the issue may be difficult if the table is so huge it can break Chrome. Is it practical for you to change the server side to return non HTML data (say, JSON data or something like that) - I can think of code that can do what you want with HTML, however, as I said, the fact that the current HTML response can break Chrome means my suggestion would break anyway

Comment: Does it have to return a table, could it return a json array of objects instead of as said above? Also could you modify the request to take a page and count parameters to return only the specified result set. Then you could return <tr></tr> instead that could be appended to the end on each request if you can't modify the return easily to json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get only 20 records each request. Loading all records is not a good approach. Imagine the situation when your result contains 1 million records?

To do so, in your ajax's data setting, you can add a parameter called "page_number" and increase it each ajax request by javascript, then on your server processing (your .php file), take that "page_number" parameter and process the result taking based on the current "page_number".

Comment: Beautiful answer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not get whole table as HTML code instead you can keep your table in main view and get 20-20 "tr" in ajax call and append only "tr" dynamically on scroll.

```
<table>
   <thead>
        //<th> goes here
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       //append tr here using jquery
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

you can use jquery like this

```
$('tbody').append(your_20_<tr>)
```